# TestNG: Iterate through array using the Dataprovider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, jxl

I'm conducting Automation testing using Selenium Webdriver,  this code is for TestNg `dataprovider`, Summary:  I am taking data from Excel sheet to data,
it's working fine.   When I'm debugging the code, I'm getting TestData as `testGoogle1(String search1, String Search2)`  for 1st Iteration it `Search1 = Webdriver, Search2 = Qtp, so on,,,,`
What I want is that it should directly return the array of values something like `testGoogle1(String search[])` so that in the `@Test` itself I can add my function iterate all the rows and columns and test them.

Can anyone please give me the idea how to write it.

Test Data sheet

[image: Test Data]

here is my code

```
package ExcelTest;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;   
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;   
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import jxl.*;


public class Sample{

      WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeTest
        public void startTest(){
            driver = Startup.basic();
        } 


@DataProvider(name = "DP1")
public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception{
     Object[][] retObjArr=getTableArray("G:\\Selenium Jar Files\\TestData\\Data.xls","DataPool");
    return(retObjArr);

}

@Test (dataProvider = "DP1")
public void testGoogle1(String search1, String Search2) throws Exception{
//selenium.open("http://www.google.co.in/");
//  driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/");

    //String hello = search.length;
//for(int i=0; i< search.length ;i++)
//{
System.out.println("param   " +search);
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("Opened");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys(search);
element.submit();
System.out.println("Clicked");
}
//}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
//selenium.stop();
}


public String[][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath,String sheetName) throws Exception{

    String[][] tabArray=null;


      File inputWorkbook = new File(xlFilePath);
        Workbook w;
        int startRow,startCol, endRow, endCol,ci,cj;
        try {
            //w = Workbook.
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(sheetName);
            // Loop over first 10 column and lines
            endRow = sheet.getRows();
            endCol = sheet.getColumns();
            tabArray=new String[endRow-1][endCol-1];

            ci=0;

            for (int i=1;i<endRow;i++,ci++){
                cj=0;
                for (int j=1;j<endCol;j++,cj++){

                  Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                tabArray[ci][cj] = cell.getContents(); 

                }
            //    System.out.println("");
            }
            //file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




       return(tabArray);
    }

}
```

Can anyone please share any idea ?
Thanks

Edited Code:

```
public class Sample{

      WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeTest
        public void startTest(){
            driver = Startup.basic();
        } 


@DataProvider(name = "DP1")
public Object[][][] createData1() throws Exception{
     Object[][][] retObjArr=getTableArray("G:\\Selenium Jar Files\\TestData\\Data.xls","DataPool");
    return (retObjArr);

}

@Test (dataProvider = "DP1")
public void testGoogle1(String search, String het) throws Exception{

System.out.println("param   " +search);
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("Opened");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys(search);
element.submit();
System.out.println("Clicked");
}
//}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
//selenium.stop();
}


public Object[][][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath,String sheetName) throws Exception{

    Object[][] tabArray=null;


      File inputWorkbook = new File(xlFilePath);
        Workbook w;
        int startRow,startCol, endRow, endCol,ci,cj,ck;
        try {
            //w = Workbook.
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(sheetName);
            // Loop over first 10 column and lines
            endRow = sheet.getRows();
            endCol = sheet.getColumns();
            tabArray=new String[endRow-1][endCol-1];

            ci=0;

            for (int i=1;i<endRow;i++,ci++){
                cj=0;

                for (int j=1;j<endCol;j++,cj++){

                  Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                tabArray[ci][cj] = cell.getContents(); 

                }
            //    System.out.println("");
            }
            //file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



       return(tabArray);  /// Here Getting the error **Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[][] to Object[][][]**
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, from this code it looks like you know how data providers work.  All you need to do is give it a 3-D array of String, and it will pass the innermost array to the test.

Comment: Iam new to this can you please help me in doing this,

Comment: Hi MrTi, Can you please help me, or give a link to solve this, iam striuck here, Not able to proceed further.

Comment: I'm personally against giving out code.  However, I am not against helping you.  Do you understand how arrays work?  If not, there are plenty of resources to help you there.  If you do, what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Hi Thanks for Replying, i was trying to give like this   @DataProvider(name = "DP1")
public Object[][][] createData1() throws Exception{
    Object[][][] retObjArr=getTableArray("G:\\Selenium Jar Files\\TestData\\Data.xls","DataPool");
    return (retObjArr);
   
}                                                                   public Object[][][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath,String sheetName) throws Exception{
    Object[][][] tabArray=null;

Comment: Please add the code to your description above.  What error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

This is how a `@DataProvider` works, assuming I have the following array:

```
[[value1, value2],
 [value3, value4],
 [value5, value6]]
```

Note that there are 3 rows and 2 columns.  The Test will be run 3 times, and passed in 2 values each time.  It doesn't matter what the value is.

Now, if you want the test to only be run once, your array should look like this:

```
[[value1]]
```

We can make `value1` to be whatever we want it to be, so if `value1` is the array above, then it will pass in the entire array to the dataProvider.  Thus, your return statement should return `{{tabArray}}`

Comment: what i understood for the edited code return should be return {{tabArray}}; ? but this is giving error.  ( Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements ) sorry iam learning completely new to this.

Comment: Put a semicolon at the end of the line.  I would recommend learning java before trying to modify code.

Comment: Thanks i will do that ( learning Java) but my doubt is  Object[][][] getTableArray is three dimensional array and Object[][] tabArray is two dimensional array that is causing problem i think so any how i have put semicolon for return {{tabArray}}; but still the same error.

Comment: You are really creating a 4-D array.  Your function can return an `Object[][]` though, because an Object can be anything.  Same error, as in, `insert ";"`?

Comment: Find the line that is throwing the error, and add a semicolon.  Anyways, my solution will work.  If you get errors, please google them, and figure out what is happening.  If you are still having problems, spend some time learning Java.  You really shouldn't be modifying code you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you very Much for your time, i will try myself Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you are trying to create a dataprovider function that returns Object[][][]. You cannot do that; the dataprovider function must return either Object[][] (a two dimensional array of any Object), or an Iterator which will perform the same function but in a slightly different way.

You can certainly nest another array inside of the 2D array that is returned; that is why it is Object[][] and not a specific type.

Also make sure you construct your return result correctly. For example, you can't do the following because that does not construct the Object[][] array:

```
return {{myArray}};
```

Instead, you would do this:

```
return new Object[][]{{myArray}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [jxl](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) is harder than it needs to be.  I wrote an example of a TestNG DataProvider [reading Excel data](https://github.com/djangofan/MetaModelExample/blob/master/src/main/java/qa/test/Data.java) using [Apache MetaModel](http://metamodel.apache.org/) (which recently became a full fledged Apache project) , and you can find that [here](https://github.com/djangofan/MetaModelExample).

```
public static Object[][] getCsvData( File csvFile ) 
    {   
        CsvConfiguration conf = new CsvConfiguration( 1 );
        DataContext csvContext = DataContextFactory.createCsvDataContext( csvFile, conf );
        Schema schema = csvContext.getDefaultSchema();
        Table[] tables = schema.getTables();
        Table table = tables[0]; // a representation of the csv file name including extension
        DataSet dataSet = csvContext.query()
                .from( table )
                .selectAll()
                .where("run").eq("Y")
                .execute();
        List<Row> rows = dataSet.toRows();
        Object[][] myArray = get2ArgArrayFromRows( rows );
        return myArray;
    }
```

And second part of that:

```
public static Object[][] get2ArgArrayFromRows( List<Row> rows ) {
        Object[][] myArray = new Object[rows.size()][2];
        int i = 0;
        SelectItem[] cols = rows.get(0).getSelectItems();
        for ( Row r : rows ) {
            Object[] data = r.getValues();
            for ( int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++ ) {
                if ( data[j] == null ) data[j] = ""; // force empty string where there are NULL values
            }
            myArray[i][0] = cols;
            myArray[i][1] = data;
            i++;
        }
        logger.info( "Row count: " + rows.size() );
        logger.info( "Column names: " + Arrays.toString( cols ) );
        return myArray;
    }
```

And an example of a test that uses this DataProvider:

```
@Test( dataProvider = "csv" )
public void testPrintCsvRowToLog( SelectItem[] cols, Object[] data ) {
    String theCols = Joiner.on("|").join( cols );
    String aRow = Joiner.on("|").join( data );
    logger.info( theCols ); 
    logger.info( aRow ); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use TestNg Parameter and Dataprovider for @Test annotation.

Better to use DataProvider annotation for BeforeTest/Beforeclass annotation and Use @Parameter annotataion for @Test annotation